# Do I need to restart after editing Anacrontab?

Tags: centos, cron

To help troubleshoot a few servers, I have edited the delay time in `Anacrontab`.

Do I need to restart anything for these changes to be applied?

Answer (score 9):

In CentOS/RHEL, anacrontab is run from cron... so you don't need to do anything.

- cron.{daily, weekly, monthly} jobs are defined in `/etc/anacrontab`
- The `anacron` command executes jobs defined in `/etc/anacrontab`
- Anacron is called from `/etc/cron.hourly/0anacron`
- `/etc/cron.d/0hourly` contains `01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly`

A little difficult to follow, but yeah...

Answer (score 3):

No. anacron isn't a separate daemon that runs continuously.  It's started periodically, say daily, by a cron job, does its work, then exits.  For example, on my Ubuntu host, /etc/cron.d/anacron contains

```
30 7    * * *   root    start -q anacron || :
```

So each time anacron runs, it starts up and rereads its configuration files.  So your changes will take effect the next time anacron runs.